# A bug of numeric::solve

Tags: matlab, numeric, solver, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

Consider

```
syms x f(x);
f = @(x) (x^2 - 4)^(1/2)/log(x^2)^2;
```

The command

```
solve(f(x)==0,x,'Real',true)
```

returns

```
ans =

  2
 -2
```

and I try

```
feval(symengine,'solve',f(x)==0,x)
feval(symengine,'numeric::solve',f(x)==0,x)
feval(symengine,'numeric::solve',f(x)==0,x,'AllRealRoots')
```

which return

```
ans =

[ 2, -2]

ans =

-1.9999947682667438275672111558379
```

and

```
ans =

[ empty sym ]
```

respectively.

Is this really a bug of `numeric::solve`?

Or I just missed some point in the commands.

All comments and suggestions are welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? In R2013b I get `-2.0` for `feval(symengine,'numeric::solve',f(x)==0,x)`. Also make sure that you read the documentation for `numeric::solve` closely. In particular, for the [`'AllRealRoots'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-solve.html#btf_mwl-6) option it clearly warns that "Note that there is no guarantee that all real solutions will be found." Are you trying to find one solution method to rule them all?

Comment: I use R2013a. Maybe this is a reason. The option 'AllRealRoots' should return at least -2 or 2, not [empty sym]. I will try them in the newer version. Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily. Read the documentation. The function apparently uses a completely different solution method in this case. Have you looked at (plotted) the real part of this function over this domain? It appears to be highly discontinuous at exactly `-2` and `2`. Numeric solution methods often have trouble in such cases. Not only that, the entire range [-2,2] is zero in the real values.

Comment: @horchler thanks a lot. f(x) is not real for all x in the interval (-2,2) and f is discontinuous at x=-2 and 2. I just know this trouble in such cases. What I really can not accept is "numeric::solve" return "empty sym" while "solve" returns some.

Comment: Why can you "not accept" this? Different solution methods behave differently, particularly in the case of discontinuities and if bounds aren't specified. That's why so many different options exist in Matlab. `numeric::solve` relies on `numeric::realroot` when `'AllRealRoots'` is used. This option is not a panacea, but comes with caveats due to how `numeric::realroot` works.

Comment: If you want a guaranteed solution you need to bracket each root above and below and use a robust root-finding method such as [regula falsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method) or [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method)  ([`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html)). The various `solve` and `numeric::solve` schemes you've tried appear to do the same *as long as you provide bounds* and use the correct options. There's no magic algorithm for finding all of the roots of a general equation without a bit of expert knowledge from the user.

Comment: ah..okay it's my misunderstanding. Really thank for the very clear explanation.